# Spring STS not loading environment variables but running maven works

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm using Mac OS Mojave with Spring STS version 3.9.7.

So I'm trying to load some environment variables such as database username & password into my application.properties file but Spring fails to load them into.

I'v used this command to set the username environment variable:

```
export ABC_DB_UNAME=some_username
```

and when I do **echo $ABC_DB_UNAME** or **printenv** I can see the value.

In my application.properties file I set the username as below:

```
spring.datasource.username=${ABC_DB_UNAME}
```

Now when running my spring sts from the IDE itself, it is not able to pick up the values and it throws an exception that

> access is denied for ABC_DB_UNAME@database_endpoint.

It clearly shows that spring sts is not picking up my environment variables.

What makes it more twisting for me is that when I run the spring app via maven using the below command, it picks up the environment variables and it works just fine.

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

but using the mvn command I don't know how I can make the IDE to trigger the breakpoints for me to debug as well.

**EDIT**: Testing and trying to print the environment variable using the code System.getenv("ABC_DB_UNAME") and System.getProperty("ABC_DB_UNAME") also returns null but maven still works.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate, I specifically stated that how I'm loading the env variables in my application.properties and the link proposed as the answer is by code approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the environmental variable is set temporarily in the terminal. Hence the `mvn spring-boot:run` works. You can run it in different terminal, it should fail

You need to set the ${ABC_DB_UNAME} in the bashrc (mac) to persist it permanently.
or you can pass the environmental variable as argument during running the app.

Comment: You are right, even though I managed to find the reason based on another stackoverflow topic that mentioned if the export is done manually in the shell, it'll be for that shell instance only. I moved everything into .bash_profile and restarted... it worked just fine. Accepting this answer still.